# Joomla Custom Parameter Types and Saving Values

Tags: php, parameters, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-module

I am new to Joomla development and I can't seem to find any decent documentation anywhere about how to solve my problem. Here is my goal: I want to create a Joomla module that allows a user to pull content from a repository and display it in a module position (my company runs 50+ websites for our resorts, and each site has common data which is very time consuming to maintain on a per-site basis). I have created my module that is able to display content items from my central content repository, and I want the user to be able to select a content snippet from all snippets available from my central repository. I have created my custom type, and it creates a select box containing the title and ID of every snippet that a user can choose. The problem that I am having is that after the user selects a snippet and saves, Joomla immediately forgets the user's choice and displays nothing. An example of the code generated by my custom parameter type is:

```
<select name="ucr_content_id">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="8">Resort Page --  Atrium</option>
    <option value="14">Resort Page -- Blue Heron</option>
    <option value="15">Resort Page -- Blue Ridge Village </option>
    <option value="16">Resort Page --  Cabins at Green Mountain</option>
    <option value="17">Resort Page -- Church Street Inn</option>

    <option value="18">Resort Page -- Ellington</option>
    <option value="19">Resort Page -- Festiva Sailing Vacations</option>
    <option value="20">Resort Page -- Frenchmen Orleans</option>
    <option value="21">Resort Page -- Main Street Inn</option>
    <option value="22">Resort Page -- Mirror Lake/Tamarack</option>
</select>
```

and the code for my custom type is:

```
<?php
class JElementSnippetList extends JElement {

var $_name = "snippetList";
function fetchElement($name, $value, &$node, $control_name) {
    // Base name of the HTML control.
    $ctrl = $control_name . '[' . $name . ']';
    $data = array();
    // Construct the various argument calls that are supported.
    if ($v = $node -> attributes('snippettype')) {
        $data["type"] = $v;
    }
    $startTag = '<select name="'.$name.'"><option value="0">None</option>'.PHP_EOL;
    $list_response = JElementSnippetList::post_request("http://path.to.repository/fetchSnippetList.php", $data);
    if($list_response["status"] == 'ok'){
        return $startTag.$list_response['content'];
    }
}

public static function post_request($url, $data) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if(is_object($value) || is_array($value)){
            $data[$key] = serialize($value);
        }
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result) {
        $output['status'] = "ok";
        $output['content'] = $result;
    } else {
        $output['status'] = "failure";
        $output['error'] = curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
}
?>
```

Also, here is my XML config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<install type="module" version="1.5.0">
<name>Universal Content Repository</name>
<author>Brendon Dugan</author>
<version>1.5.0</version>
<description>A module to allow the insertion of UCR Snippets into a Joomla site.</description>
<files>
    <filename>mod_ucr.xml</filename>
    <filename module="mod_ucr">mod_ucr.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>helper.php</filename>
    <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
    <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
    <filename>elements/snippetList.php</filename>
    <filename>elements/index.html</filename>
</files>
<params addpath="/modules/mod_ucr/elements">
    <param name="ucr_repository" type="text" default="http://path.to.repository/" label="Repository Fetch URL" description="" size="40" />
    <param name="ucr_script_id" type="snippetList" snippettype="js" default="" label="Script ID" description="" />
    <param name="ucr_css_id" type="snippetList" snippettype="css" default="" label="CSS ID" description="" size="10" />
    <param name="ucr_content_id" type="snippetList" snippettype="content" default="" label="Content ID" description="" size="10" />
</params>
</install>
```

Any ideas? I have looked at the following tutorials, but as with most of Joomla's documentation they seem to leave out critical information:

[Custom Parameter Types](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_custom_template_parameter_types)

[Multi-Item Select Parameter Type](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_a_multiple_item_select_list_parameter_type)

[SQLMultiSelectX](http://docs.joomla.org/SQLMultiSelectX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have found a solution to the problem. Apparently you have to use the $value parameter to specify a value in the getSnippetContent() function.